# window unload method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

Why doesn't this code work?

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
});
```

Comment: If this was possible, you could in theory "lock" the user to stay in your website forever without the ability to navigate away, unless he close the browser. It's really bad thing, so I assume that's the reason the browsers won't allow such thing. What's your final goal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome do **not** allow a `location` change after the `unload` or `beforeunload` events have fired.

So your code might work in IE and Opera, but will (what I assume to be good behavior) fail in the other two Browser that I've named.

Comment: Well it worked the last time I tested it in the IE9 beta, that's the only IE version I have available. But after all, just don't mess around with `unload` events, they are unreliable, nothing you put in them is really guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2):

`href` is not present in you redirection

```
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

Comment: There's a `window` object.
The `window` object has a `location` object as one of its properties.
The `location` object has `href` as a property. The `href` property needs to be set for redirection.

Comment: `window.location` has a setter that will, just as `href` does, change the current location.

Comment: "You can also assign to this property to load another URL." - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location, where 'this property' refers to the `location` object

Comment: Guys, I personally think that this is due to the method of "unload"

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `unload` event is called when the user moves away from the page (for any reason: he can close the browser, click on a link, insert a new url, click 'back'...) and should be used only for messages or confirmations (like 'Are you sure?') or any actions that do not interfere with user choice.

See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) for some suggestions.

Comment: Actually the "Are you sure" can be used only in the `onbeforeunload` event.